# Change border width in specific cell of eCharts heatmap

Tags: echarts, apache-echarts

i'm trying to change the border of the middle cell to give emphasis at it.

i could change border for the entire chart with `series-heatmap.itemStyle` but not for only one cell.

the result i'm expecting looks like the image above:

[image]

any help will be appreciated!!

**[EDIT]**

I found in the [docs](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#series-heatmap.data) that if customization was needed for some specific item, it could be setted up in `data` array:

```js
[
    12,
    24,
    {
        value: [24, 32],
        // label style, only works in this data item.
        label: {},
        // item style, only works in this data item.
        itemStyle:{}
    },
    33
]
// Or
[
    [12, 332],
    [24, 32],
    {
        value: [24, 32],
        // label style, only works in this data item.
        label: {},
        // item style, only works in this data item.
        itemStyle:{}
    },
    [33, 31]
]
```

my data serie is setted like:

```js
[[0, 0, 549], [0, 1, 571] ...
```

already tyried to change only the array with "653" in the midle follow those examples but without success...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to solve that

just add a new series with the value with i want to change the border

as my `DataSerie` is an array of arrays of lenght 62, just need to place the mean value in the second series:

### DataSerie Example

[[0,0,1], [0,0,2], ... ]

```js
ChartOptions = {
...
  series: [
    {
      type: 'heatmap',
      data: DataSerie
    },
    {
      type: "heatmap",
      // [ [x, y, value] ]
      data: [ [DataSerie[31] ]
    }
  ]
...
```